# Is a letter considered to be in alphabetical order with itself?

Tags: alphabet, sort-ordering

We've come across a maths problem regarding car license plates. Their format is XXN where each X is a letter from A-D, and N is a digit. For example "AA0, AB1, CB9, etc"

One of the questions asked is to calculate what fraction of all possible plates have their letters "in alphabetical order" and my 10-year old asked me: "is a plate that repeats the same letter twice such as AA1 considered to be in alphabetical order"?

While I am inclined to say yes, the objection is that the alphabet never repeats the same letter twice, it is always increasing.

Comment: Not sure if this is an English language question, since it applies to all languages that use an alphabet.

Comment: I think most people would generally interpret "AA" to be in alphabetical order (which would appear before "AB", "AC", etc.) but its definition for the purposes of this maths problem is entirely in the control of the question setter.

Comment: If you are given the task of placing in "alphabetical order: cards labeled with individual letters then obviously if there were two "A" cards they would be placed together.  But what it means in your example is unclear.

Comment: @KillingTime I must be in the minority! In "AA" there is no order. If they were in alphabetical order, then reversing the letters would put them out of order, and that's not possible.

Comment: 'In alphabetical order' is probably best seen as a fixed term, corresponding to 'the order in which words etc would be listed in a typical dictionary', rather than an analysable construction ('but there's no 'order' to the B's in BB5'). Thus AA0, AA1 ... AB0, AB1 .... giving the fraction 5/8. But good mathematicians should anticipate such terminological ambiguities and give specifying definitions (eg "For the purposes of this question, 'eels' has its letters in alphabetical order").

Comment: Isn't this the paradox of the barber who shaves only those who don't shave themselves? If A and A are what's meant by alphabetic order, paradox must then be listed as a rhyme of paradox. Yes, you can use it in the rhyming position out of desperation, but really?

Comment: The solution is to provide both answers.  If “AA1” is considered to be in order then the answer is X.  If not, the answer is Y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: In math AAB is ordered, it is alphabetically ordered, but it is not strictly ordered.

In math, the assumption is yes, and you need to specify if it is not the case. Alphabets are [totally ordered sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order)

In math, the term "ordered" means the operator has three properties. The one we are interested in is *connexity*. This property is: a<=b or b<=a for all a,b. With respect to AAB:  it is ordered.

If you change the connexity property, you say "strictly ordered". AAB is not strictly ordered. If you need to discriminate between the two, you can use "non-strictly ordered" to refer to the former.

There are two recognized ways to alphabetize strings of letters. They differ in how they handle strings with different numbers of letters. But since the length is specified here, it doesn't matter, both will yield the same result.

The difficulty with these terms is that they are defined in a very general manner. The definitions are hard to understand at first glance, and mathematicians are loath to provide examples that lose generality.

Comment: Ah. Belongs on Maths.SE. The specifying definitions are not part of standard English usage (I wasn't aware of the terminology of ordering beyond set level, and I taught maths beyond A-Level). _However, the setters of the question probably haven't the expertise needed to foresee the potential problem, picked up by a bright 10-year-old._

Answer (score 2):

Your maths problem restricts letters to a-d, so this is clearly not a problem about English language. To answer the question correctly, you need to ask the person who stated the question. As asked, the question is ambiguous.

A mathematician would have called it either “in increasing alphabetical order” or “in non-decreasing alphabetical order”. The letters AA would definitely not be “in increasing alphabetical order”, but would definitely be “in non-decreasing alphabetical order”.

In general, the question would be very country dependent. German license plates for example are not restricted to the letters a-z. There are 1 to 3 initial letters, followed by a hyphen and another letter, followed by digits but not 0 as the first digit. However, only about 700 of the 1-3 letter combinations are allowed.

In the U.K. on the other hand, the rules have changed over time, and as a result sorting correctly is a lot more complicated.

Comment: I cannot but downvote an answer containing 'this is clearly not a problem about English language'. I'd say it is on-topic in that it asks about a precising/specifying definition of 'alphabetical', but off-topic because answers will be arbitrary / 'unclear'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, shouldn't the determination of whether a **question** is on topic be based on what it **asks**, rather than on what the answer turns out to be? Explaining that a word is imprecise in ordinary usage, and how it could be made more precise, **is** a part of explaining its meaning.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Many seem to agree with you that my question is off-topic. I am however satisfied with the answer that "in this context, the question is ambiguous, here's how it could've been clearly stated". I did consider deleting my question, but I will leave it to a moderator to decide. I'm just glad that everyone seems to agree on this answer.

Comment: @jsw29 'This is an answer to a question clearly off-topic'  has at least one serious fault; I downvoted the answer. After Phil Sweet's answer, which seems correct (though supporting evidence is not posted clearly), it becomes clear that this is a question about 'strictly ordered' vs 'ordered' as defined in maths usage. So, it belongs on maths, as 'ordered' is not well-defined in everyday English.